# Resolving SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementBadResponse

Tags: azure, api, azureportal, scim

I have implemented this [SCIM reference code](https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode) in our application.

My implemented code did pass all the test collection of **Users** present in this [postman link](https://aka.ms/ProvisioningPostman). My **SCIM Api** was also accepted by Azure as the valid endpoint for Users.

The real problem starts when I tried to perform **Provision on Demand** from the **Azure portal** for a User.

I received the following error code: **SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementBadResponse**

**Error Message:** A required attribute is missing from a response.  The missing attribute is Identifier.  Here is the response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User": {},
        "active": true,
        "displayName": "Chris Brown",
        "emails": [
            {
                "type": "work",
                "primary": true,
                "value": "chris.brown@xyz.com"
            }
        ],
        "meta": {
            "resourceType": "User",
            "created": "2022-04-21T05:27:03.774148Z",
            "lastModified": "2022-04-21T05:27:03.774148Z",
            "version": null,
            "location": null
        },
        "name": {
            "formatted": "Chris Brown",
            "familyName": "Brown",
            "givenName": "Chris"
        },
        "preferredLanguage": "en-GB",
        "userName": "chris.brown@xyz.com",
        "externalId": "chris.brown",
        "id": "a99b4da2-ab2f-49fc-8a01-4a9ce251fbdb",
        "schemas": [
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
            "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
        ]
    },
    "targetUrl": null,
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
}
```

As you can clearly see, I have added `id` (the Identifier) to the response. Now I am confused about what the error message conveys.

Please help.

An image for clear understanding of the error message at Azure Portal:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response doesn't align with the SCIM spec. The response to the POST (I think that's what it is, given the screenshot) is nesting the actual response inside of a "Result" object that is not defined in the spec at all.

Take a look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7644#section-3.3 for an example of a correct response to a POST.

Also, there are a number of attributes in your response, outside of the "request" attribute/object, that aren't defined in the spec and are therefore noncompliant. Those would be:

"targetUrl": null,
"success": true,
"error": null,
"unAuthorizedRequest": false,